# Winter Bash stats page is listing the stats from 2017

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

The [Winter Bash stats page](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/stats) is listing the stats from the 2017 Winter Bash ([archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20180110151511/https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/stats) for comparison). For reference [2018](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/04/adios-to-winter-bash-2018/) displayed the correct stats.

The stats are useful, I miss this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated the stats (it has to be done manually). At the very least they will be updated again after WB 2019 ends.

### Update: Final stats for WB2019 have been posted

Comment: Thank you! and please do update again once the bash is over.